# Zendesk: anyone knows how to authenticate in Zendesk API?

Tags: python, postman, zendesk, zendesk-api

I am trying to connect to Zendesk with API token, but I am getting this issue:

```
{
    "error": "Couldn't authenticate you"
}
```

I am trying to use `Basic Auth` (here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQDfU.png) from Postman).

If anyone knows another way how to do it, share it with me please!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/ticketing/getting-started/zendesk-api-quick-start/#preparation) you can enable password and email as auth:

> 1. If you don't already have a Zendesk Support account, register to start a free trial at https://www.zendesk.com/register/
> 2. In your browser, navigate to your Zendesk account. The url will look something like https://your_subdomain.zendesk.com.
> 3. In Admin Center, click the Apps and integrations icon () in the sidebar, then select APIs > Zendesk APIs. Under the Settings tab, make sure Password Access is enabled in the settings. If you don't have permissions to do this, ask an admin to check for you.

[image: enable zendesk password and email auth]

---

There are also ways to use OAuth or an API Token. See this article:
[How can I authenticate API requests?](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000510267-How-can-I-authenticate-API-requests-)

> If you use an API token, combine your email address and API token to generate the authorization header.
> The email address and API token combination need to be a Base-64 encoded string.
> The authorization header should be formatted like this:

```
Authorization: Basic email_address/token:api_token
```

Comment: Does this work for accounts that sign in via Google? It doesn't seem to.

Comment: @andrewlundy, you probably need to follow the oauth procedure described in the second link https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408831452954

Comment: I have tried this already, thank you though. I've got a ticket open with Zendesk Support to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 2):

Is that your zendesk site address? If not, change it to..

https://TypeYourSiteHere.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json

Your zendesk account also needs to be an administrator for it to work with basic auth.